# cfmailparam file and charset

Tags: encoding, utf-8, coldfusion

I generate a CSV file as one string with semicolons as field separator and chr(13) chr(10) as line separator. I append this to an email with the `cfmailparam` tag using `disposition="attachment"` and the `content` attribute contains the said string. The attachment of the mail seems to be encoded in UTF8 which Excel does not like, so my Umlauts are destroyed. Is there a possibility to provide the cfmailparam tag with a charset attribute to ensure the file is attached/sent Windows1252 encoded?

Is it better to store the string with the `cffile` tag and the Windows1252 encoding and appending it to the mail with the cfmailparam file attribute?

```
<cfset arrTitel = [
    "Titel"
    , "Geschäftsbereich"
]>

<cfsavecontent variable="csv"><cfoutput><cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen( arrTitel )#" index="spaltentitel"><cfif spaltentitel gt 1>;</cfif>"#arrTitel[spaltentitel]#</cfloop>#chr(13)##chr(10)#</cfoutput></cfsavecontent>

<cfmail from="#mail#" to="#mailempf#" subject="subj" type="text/html">
    <cfmailparam
    content="#csv#"
    disposition="attachment"
    file="Report.csv"
    >
</cfmail>
```

This is what it basically looks like.
Please don't advise to change the encoding of the cfm file. Other values containing Umlauts are not hard coded but come from a database.

Comment: If you open the generated CSV file directly in Excel before you even email it, does it open ok, or does that also mess your special characters?  I.e. is the problem really something happening to your attachment when you email it, or is it actually when you create the file in the first place?

Comment: I don't have a file before sending, so I cannot tell. I don't even exactly know when and how Coldfusion generates a file from the string to attach it to a mail.

Comment: Show us the code that creates the content you're using for the email attachment.

Comment: If you are using semicolens as delimiters, perhaps a .txt extension would be more appropriate that .csv.

Comment: @Bardware - I think what duncan was suggesting was create some test files in both UTF8 and 1252 and see how Excel handles them. Also, just to rule things out, any difference if you set the message charset to something other than UTF8? The latter may introduce other issues, but it would be good to know the outcome of those three (3) tests.

Comment: " I don't even exactly know when and how Coldfusion generates a file from the string to attach it to a mail". *Finding out* is part of troubleshooting this.